# -moz-background-clip: *text* in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, mozilla, gecko

Is there a good way to implement this in Mozilla? I have done it successfully in Webkit using -webkit-background-clip: text;. I have been trying to implement it into Firefox with no success. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip) has it listed as -moz-background-clip but there is no 'text' attribute. The finalized CSS3 attribute is background-clip but I have not been able to find if 'text' is a valid option across engines or if it is a webkit only thing. Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Comment: More solution alternatives are available as answers to question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13932946

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Webkit is on their own in supporting this feature at this point. Found an interesting cross-browser variation that uses SVG though: http://www.myadzel.ru/tests/html/text-background/.

Comment: That's what I came up with after about half an hour of research. Interesting... I might see how that works. If I find anything else out I'll report back.

Comment: I made your answer the solution because I'm pretty sure you're right about it being webkit only. Thanks for the help. Hopefully this will change, or there will be a better way. Web standards are always changing!

Comment: Thanks for the vote. We'll just have to wait and see whether other browsers eventually pick this setting up. Hopefully so! In case you haven't already found it, I always keep my eye on www.css3.info for news about which web standards are being added by various browsers and W3C.

Comment: Just FYI it's not a standard.