# css letterpress firefox not working

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this letterpress effect with my own font and it is perfectly working on Chrome and Safari.

```
.letterpress {
    text-align: center;
    font: 95px peskeu;
    background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
}
```

I have recently seen that `-moz-background-clip:text;` does not work.
Help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question on stack overflow. The answer mentioned is good and explanatory 
Since webkit has its own support for this so its better to get a hack for this. Link below provides one.
[-moz-background-clip: *text* in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466650/moz-background-clip-text-in-mozilla)